# How I can parallel call methods with async keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Now I have 3 methods

```
    IList<Car> cars = Service.GetCars(20);
    IList<Shoe> shoes = Service.GetShoes(20);
    IList<Bike> bike = Service.GetBikes(20);
```

I want to parallel the calls with async keywords and await. I really don't understand how to. Below is a summary of a GetMethod... where y put the async keyword? where i create the Task? I want to do as simple as the async js lib. https://github.com/caolan/async/

```
   public IList<Car> GetCars(int num){
        return repository.GetCars(num);
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to call all three methods at once, you need to call the async versions:

```
var carTask = Service.GetCarsAsync(20);
var showTask = Service.GetShoesAsync(20);
var bikeTask = Service.GetBikesAsync(20);
IList<Car> cars = await carTask;
IList<Shoe> shoes = await shoeTask;
IList<Bike> bike = await bikeTask;
```

The first three lines start the asynchronous operations, which each return a `Task<IList<T>>`.  The `await` calls "await" their completion and return the actual values.

You could write these on the same lines, but splitting them as above causes all three async operations to *start immediately* and then fetches the results as they come back.  If you put them on the same line, ie: `IList<Car> cars = await Service.Get...`, then the operations would stay asynchronous, but the second wouldn't start until the first completed.

If you're writing the method yourself, you'd need to wrap the call.  If you don't have an option for an existing asynchronous method, you can wrap it:

```
public Task<IList<Car>> GetCars(int num)
{
    return Task.Run(() => repository.GetCars(num));
}
```

However, if your `repository` supports asynchronous methods, it would be better to use them directly instead of calling `Task.Run`, since this is really wrapping an async call around synchronous code, by using a ThreadPool thread.  In general, that's not a good design, as it's better to leave sync code sync and wrap it at the usage point instead of "hiding" the fact that it's not really asynchronous.

Comment: So I don't need the keyword async in the GetCarsMethod?

Comment: @elranu If `repository` supports an asynchronous version of GetCars, you can just return it directly.  If you need to do other work in there, then maybe you need it, but you don't *necessarily* need it to be there.

Comment: one last question: if awaits are like that a line below the other. It will do it in Parallel? or until cars return a value, GetShoes wont be call? It is not better to do at the end Task.WhenAll(cars, shoes, bikes); ?

Comment: I recommend using `await Task.WhenAll` to better propagate errors and have more determinism.

Comment: @elranu Since I launched the tasks one at a time, THEN await them, the tasks will all run at the same time.  It won't fetch results until for shoes until cars are available, but the three will all be running at once.

Comment: @usr That complicates things a bit - but it will allow you to catch errors from all three tasks if needed, so it can be nice if that's required.

Answer (score 0):

Create a task for each method, wait them all like that:

```
Task stuff1 = Task.Run(() => Service.GetStuff1());
...
Task.WaitAll(stuff1, stuff2, stuff3);
```

Comment: Since this is a "Service" call, the service should be able to support async calls directly.  Better to use them than `Task.Run` if possible, since that fires up a ThreadPool thread for the call.  (This also does take advantage of async/await)